# Flutter: How can i improve that app performance?

Tags: android, performance, flutter, mobile, dart

I want to know why that Flutter code is below 60 fps in some devices (Redmi Go, in that case, profiling mode, showing red bars in UI graph). Is there any way i could optimize it? I began to study Flutter yesterday so i want some tips to help me understand stateful widgets and widgets rendering hierarchy in general.

Thanks in advance.

File **main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:project/ui/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
      home: BillSplitter(),
    ));
```

File **home.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BillSplitter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BillSplitterState createState() => _BillSplitterState();
}

class _BillSplitterState extends State<BillSplitter> {
  int _tipPercentage = 0;
  int _personCounter = 1;
  double _billAmount = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "APP Teste 1.0",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.5),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.5),
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 150,
              height: 150,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.1),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Total por pessoa",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.purple,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          fontSize: 17.0),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "R\$ ${_calculateTotalPerPerson(_billAmount, _personCounter, _tipPercentage)}",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.purple,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 35.0),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.blueGrey.shade100,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    keyboardType:
                        TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixText: "Total da Conta: R\$ ",
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money)),
                    onChanged: (String value) {
                      try {
                        _billAmount = double.parse(value);
                      } catch (e) {
                        _billAmount = 0.0;
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Dividir",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                if (_personCounter > 1) {
                                  _personCounter--;
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              width: 40.0,
                              height: 40.0,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                                  color: Colors.purpleAccent.withOpacity(0.1)),
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                "-",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.purple,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 17.0),
                              )),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "$_personCounter",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.purple,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 17.0),
                          ),
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _personCounter++;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              width: 40.0,
                              height: 40.0,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                                  color: Colors.purpleAccent.withOpacity(0.1)),
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                "+",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.purple,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 17.0),
                              )),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Gorjeta",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "R\$ ${(_calculateTotalTip(_billAmount, _personCounter, _tipPercentage)).toStringAsFixed(2)}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.purple,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 17.0),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "$_tipPercentage%",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.purple,
                            fontSize: 17.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Slider(
                          activeColor: Colors.purple,
                          inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
                          min: 0,
                          max: 100,
                          divisions: 10,
                          value: _tipPercentage.toDouble(),
                          onChanged: (double value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _tipPercentage = value.round();
                            });
                          })
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _calculateTotalPerPerson(double billAmount, int splitBy, int tipPercentage) {
    double totalPerPerson =
        (billAmount + _calculateTotalTip(billAmount, splitBy, tipPercentage)) /
            splitBy;

    return totalPerPerson.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }

  _calculateTotalTip(double billAmount, int splitBy, int tipPercentage) {
    double totalTip = 0.0;

    if (billAmount < 0 || billAmount.toString().isEmpty || billAmount == null) {
    } else {
      totalTip = (billAmount * tipPercentage) / 100;
    }

    return totalTip;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to run the app in release mode to see the real impact. Do `flutter run --release` or build release apk by `flutter build apk`(this will produce flat arm64 and 32 included app)[https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android].

Comment: How can i debug/show framerate in release mode?

Comment: You can use Dart DevTools for that.

Comment: Does DevTools work in release mode?

Answer (score 6):

You are using a single large build function, you need to split it into different widgets, because when the data state changes and you call `setState()`, all descendant widgets will rebuild, so avoid using a very huge nested build function which will be very costly.

Also the performance of the application is affected by debugging, generating a release application will be more helpful to decide.

run this command to build your application
`flutter build apk`.

you can also check [Build and release an Android app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) or [Build and release an iOS app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios)

You can use Flutter profiling tools to determine the performance and determine performance problems in your application, you can find more useful details in the following link about Flutter performance profiling.

[Flutter performance profiling](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/ui-performance)

also check this link for more information and details about performance best practices.

[Performance best practices](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices)

**Update**

According to [Performance best practices](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices)

> Avoid overly large single Widgets with a large build() function. Split
>   them into different Widgets based on encapsulation but also on how
>   they change: When setState() is called on a State, all descendent
>   widgets will rebuild. Therefore, localize the setState() call to the
>   part of the subtree whose UI actually needs to change. Avoid calling
>   setState() high up in the tree if the change is contained to a small
>   part of the tree.

and according to the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of
>   this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface
>   in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for
>   this State object.

So it's way much better to divide your code to small widgets to avoid large nested widgets in a long build function, and I recommend reading about [State management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt), it's very useful for managing data around your application and improves readability and maintainability for your code, which will eventually lead to a better performance.

Here i'm providing an example about widget decoupling using the code provided in this question, you need to read the comments in the following code to understand how I divided the application widgets, and I used flutter performance and frames per second didn't fall under 30 in debug mode, while the code you provided was dropping to below 15 frames per second.

You can compare both codes and see the difference in performance, and don't hesitate to ask me about the code for clarification.

File **home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/*
  I created this class for a better data management around the application
  but this design is not recommended
 */
class Bill {
  static int _tipPercentage = 0;
  static int _personCounter = 1;
  static double _billAmount = 0.0;

  static _calculateTotalPerPerson(
      double billAmount, int splitBy, int tipPercentage) {
    double totalPerPerson =
        (billAmount + _calculateTotalTip(billAmount, splitBy, tipPercentage)) /
            splitBy;

    return totalPerPerson.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }

  static _calculateTotalTip(double billAmount, int splitBy, int tipPercentage) {
    double totalTip = 0.0;

    if (billAmount < 0 || billAmount.toString().isEmpty || billAmount == null) {
    } else {
      totalTip = (billAmount * tipPercentage) / 100;
    }

    return totalTip;
  }
}

// I converted the main widget to a stateless widget
// and for a better data management I highly recommend searching about
// state management
class BillSplitter extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "APP Teste 1.0",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.5),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.white,
        /*
        Inside this ListView a lot of children widgets which can be converted
        to smaller widgets in different classes based on the state of the widget
        either it's stateless or stateful
         */
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.5),
          children: <Widget>[
            CurrentBillContainer(), //Check this widget class down below
            BillCalculator(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/*
  This container is for the upper pink box which holds the bill value
  and viewed in a different widget with a different build function
  which will enhance the build() function time
 */
class CurrentBillContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CurrentBillContainerState createState() => _CurrentBillContainerState();
}

class _CurrentBillContainerState extends State<CurrentBillContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 150,
      height: 150,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.1),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Total por pessoa",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontSize: 17.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(
                "R\$ ${Bill._calculateTotalPerPerson(Bill._billAmount, Bill._personCounter, Bill._tipPercentage)}",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 35.0),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BillCalculator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BillCalculatorState createState() => _BillCalculatorState();
}

class _BillCalculatorState extends State<BillCalculator> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.blueGrey.shade100, style: BorderStyle.solid),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TotalBillTextField(),
          DividirRow(),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Gorjeta",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                child: Text(
                  "R\$ ${(Bill._calculateTotalTip(Bill._billAmount, Bill._personCounter, Bill._tipPercentage)).toStringAsFixed(2)}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.purple,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 17.0),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "${Bill._tipPercentage}%",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    fontSize: 17.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Slider(
                  activeColor: Colors.purple,
                  inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                  divisions: 10,
                  value: Bill._tipPercentage.toDouble(),
                  onChanged: (double value) {
                    setState(() {
                      Bill._tipPercentage = value.round();
                    });
                  })
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

/*
  Take this TextField as an example you can create a stateless widget for it
  and place it inside the column of BillCalculator class
  and you can apply the same concept all over the application,
  and divide widgets to small classes and inside sub folders to reduce the size
  of the build function and optimize the performance and make it easier to
  maintain and add a new features in your application
 */
class TotalBillTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixText: "Total da Conta: R\$ ",
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.attach_money)),
      onChanged: (String value) {
        try {
          Bill._billAmount = double.parse(value);
        } catch (e) {
          Bill._billAmount = 0.0;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

/*
  This row has to be a Stateful widget because you are using
  setState() function, you can apply the same method to all of the widgets
 */
class DividirRow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DividirRowState createState() => _DividirRowState();
}

class _DividirRowState extends State<DividirRow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "Dividir",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700),
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (Bill._personCounter > 1) {
                    Bill._personCounter--;
                  }
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 40.0,
                height: 40.0,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                    color: Colors.purpleAccent.withOpacity(0.1)),
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "-",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.purple,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 17.0),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "${Bill._personCounter}",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 17.0),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  Bill._personCounter++;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 40.0,
                height: 40.0,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                    color: Colors.purpleAccent.withOpacity(0.1)),
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "+",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.purple,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 17.0),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you check the code, you will see that setState() 'steps' doesn't have many descendent widgets. Also, could you provide example of 'widget decoupling' in my case?

Comment: What I meant by descendant widgets was the widgets inside the build function, the code you provided in your question has too many nested widgets all inside a single Stateful widget which will definitely affect the application performance and will make it really difficult for you to maintain your code.

I will update my answer with an example to widget decoupling based on your provided code, and provide some explanation about `setState()`.

Comment: I tested your code approach and the app didn't work as intended.

Comment: You made ```CurrentBillContainer``` stateful but that widget isn't updating when data changes, only when ```TotalBillTextField```changes.

Comment: Also, in my case, what are the best options in terms of state management?

Comment: sorry about that bug, I didn't really know how the application work, my only focus was optimizing performance as you mentioned in your question, maybe I forgot about updating a variable or something i'm not really sure, so by fixing my code it will probably work as intended with better performance.

and for the state management I highly recommend reading about [Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), it's really easy to implement and understand, and you will find lot's of resources about it online.